# On change event won't fire select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cascadingdropdown

I can't seem to get jQuery to fire and on change event for the county_id select list. I have tried multiple code snippets and none will fire the on change. Any ideas?

HTML:

```html
<select id="county_id" name="county_id">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Somewhere</option>
    <option value="2">Somewhere else</option>
</select>

<select id="vice_county_id" name="vice_county_id"></select>
```

JS:

```js
$(function(ready) {
    $("#county_id").change(
            function() {
                $("#vice_county_id").html("");
                var co_id = $("#county_id > option[@selected]").attr("value");
                if (co_id != 0) {
                    $.getJSON('./vice_county_web_service.php?co_id=' + co_id,
                            function(data) {
                                $.each(data, function() {
                                    $("#vice_county_id").append(
                                            $("<option></option>").val(
                                                    this['value']).html(
                                                    this['name']));
                                });
                            });
                }
            });

});
```

Comment: Did you see any error on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is firing, but this line of code is failing:

```
var co_id = $("#county_id > option[@selected]").attr("value");
```

...because that's an invalid selector. In your browser's JavaScript console, you should be seeing `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@selected]`.

jQuery will happily get you the value, just use `val`:

```
var co_id = $("#county_id").val();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ocihok) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ocihok/edit)

Comment: Great thanks, I appreciate it. Also mgraph below for the full snippet with input also from T.J. If I could tag you both I would. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

just enough to get value of select box

```
var co_id = $("#county_id").val();
```

You should use  [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)

```
$('#county_id').on('change', function() {
  //....
  var co_id = $("#county_id").val(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#county_id").change(function() {
        $("#vice_county_id").html("");
        var co_id = $(this).val();
        if(county_id != 0) {
            $.getJSON('./vice_county_web_service.php?co_id=' + co_id,function(data) {   
                $.each(data, function() {
                    $("#vice_county_id").append($("<option></option>").val(this['value']).html(this['name']));
                });
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Still has the invalid selector.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok i change it by `$(this).val();`

Answer (score 0):

Change `var co_id = $("#county_id > option[@selected]").attr("value");' to 'var co_id = $("#county_id > option:selected").attr("value");'

http://jsfiddle.net/XvRsV/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine means the change event is getting handled by the code properly Please refer this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PPuCS/)

```
$(function(ready){
            $("#county_id").change(function() {
                $("#vice_county_id").html("test");
                var co_id= $("#county_id").attr("value");
                alert('Value : ' +co_id); 
            if(co_id != 0) {
                $.getJSON('./vice_county_web_service.php?co_id=' + co_id,function(data) {    
                    $.each(data, function() {
                        $("#vice_county_id").append($("<option></option>").val(this['value']).html(this['name']));
                    });
                });
            }
        });

    });​
```

Change this line only,

var co_id= $("#county_id").attr("value");

Just check if your ajax call is working or not

Answer (score -1):

```
 <select id="county_id" name="county_id" onchange="ChangeCountry();">

function ChangeCountry()
{
   var _countryId = $('#county_id').val();
}
```